# Calling out a function, not defined error

Tags: python, class

I'm new to making classes and I'm trying to complete exercise 9-1 in my 'Python Crash Course' book where the last part of the question asks me to call back my method but I end up getting

> 'not defined error' for `describe_restaurant()`.

**Here is my code:**

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, r_name, c_type):
        self.r_name = r_name
        self.c_type = c_type

    def describe_restaurant():
        print(self.r_name.title())
        print(self.c_type.title())

    def open_restaurant():
        print(self.r_name + " is now open!")

Restaurant = Restaurant('Joe\'s Sushi', 'sushi')

print(Restaurant.r_name)
print(Restaurant.c_type)

describe_restaurant()
open_restaurant()
```

I thought that `describe_restaurant` shouldn't need to be defined though because I'm calling it out as a function to use?

Comment: You should firstly create `Restaraunt` object and then calling `describe_restaurant` from newly created object

Comment: It's a class function. You need to call the class function with a class object.

Comment: You should revisit the lesson plan on Classes. Here is another look via the official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: You need to add the `self` parameter to your method definitions inside the `Restaurant` class. Also, don't shadow your class name with an instance! Finally, you need to call the method using an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, r_name, c_type):
        self.r_name = r_name
        self.c_type = c_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(self.r_name)
        print(self.c_type)

    def open_restaurant(self):
        return "{} is now open!".format(self.r_name)

restaurant = Restaurant('Joe\'s Sushi', 'sushi')

print(restaurant.r_name)
print(restaurant.c_type)

restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

You need to create a class instance and call it's functions. In addition, as mentioned in the comments, you need to pass `self` to the instance methods. A short explanation of this can be found [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Fixed that in my snippet. Did not see...

Comment: Fixed that. Sorry, was a bit confused about myself :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, I haven't had much time to code lately. I'll take a look at your link, hopefully it will help me understand functions and classes better. :)